# Sails.js disable query params in find blueprint

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Currently cleaning up some of the code in my sails backend and I'm not too sure how to configure properly the blueprint for the particular controller.

So I want one of my endpoint to always return only the last 10 results and disable the ability for limit/find/where as a query param. So far I've done this simply by overriding find  in the controller but I was wondering if there was a way to configure the blueprint.

I've added in the controller _config the following, which allows to set default values but can still be replaced with ?limit=15.

_config: {
    sort: 'id_str desc',
    limit: 5
  }

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a policy that executes upon find requests to your model.

api/policies/limitResults.js

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  req.query.limit = 10;
  req.query.sort = 'id_str desc';
  return next();
}
```

config/policies.js

```
ModelController: {
  'find': ['limitResults']
}
```

This should overwrite the limit parameter of the request and sort the results in descending order.

Comment: Thanks, might go that way but I'm not finding it really elegant ... I might end up modifying the find blueprint to allow maximum limit and other options to be set on the route. I was just expecting this feature to be already in the codebase and was just unable to find it.

Comment: This is the correct way. Not sure what's inelegant about 4 lines of code.